# File not found - Laravel - Trying to access private folder

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-4, typeahead.js

The framework I am using is Laravel 4.2. I have a `.json` file stored in my `/app/database/seeds/json` folder, intentionally to stop people from accessing it in my public directory (it's information that I've paid for, and so I don't want people accessing it).

I am trying to access this in a 'typeahead` style feature, but it can never find the file. Currently, the script is:

```
var location = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '/app/database/seeds/json/file.json'
});
```

But in Google inspect, it returns the error:
`http://localhost:8888/app/database/seeds/json/file.json 404 (Not Found)`.

Is there a way of even accessing this file? Or can I use my public file and yet still have some protection on people accessing it?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Anything which needs to be publicly accessible, but which comes as part of a package, needs to be published.

Perhaps something like this would get it working:

```
php artisan asset:publish --path="app/database/seeds/json/file.json" bloodhound/json/file.json
```

If that worked, the file would be accessible from the URL `/packages/bloodhound/json/file.json`

Comment: But this would still mean it's available to copy?

Comment: So you want it to be accessible by the browser, but not by the user of the browser? No, this cannot be done. If you ship the data to the browser it can be viewed. Period.

Comment: So the only way around it would be to query the database using typeahead? Instead of loading it locally?

Comment: Sure. But any portion you send back will be viewable/copy-able/etc.